# Making Google Login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, google-authentication

I am creating a google login in laravel and I am getting this error:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Timed
>   out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)in
>   CurlFactory.php line 186

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue

My code is here:

```
Routes: Route::get('auth/google', 'GoogleController@redirectToProvider')->name('google.login');
Route::get('/auth/google/callback', 'GoogleController@handleProviderCallback');
```

View :

```
 <a href="{{ route('google.login')}}">
                <img src="images/google.png"/>
            </a>
```

in services.php i have added

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => '551801668180-ltjgbha1q8tp2hknmu1c2kvl5fouogm9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret' => 'l1LyPNmpZtn_GFrKVfH81fP8',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback',
    ],
```

GoogleController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Socialite;

class GoogleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        dd($user);
        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: @pagep I have added the code please check

Comment: Can you telnet from the server to that URL on port 443?